# Is there in inverse to Pandas' df.all?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove rows where all values for each column heading is False. I know df.all returns whether all elements are True, potentially over an axis, but is there something for the inverse, where I want to return elements that have at least one True in the row?

Comment: is it `df.any(1)`?

Comment: Hey! I think that worked, so now it returns True if all the entire row was false. Do you have any idea on how I'd remove the rows from the original dataframe based on this ?

Comment: @etnie1031 Just do: ```df2 = df[df.any(1)]```

Comment: ah, great! Thanks guys